# innerHTML part of <div> not showing up when appending child to <div>

Tags: javascript, html

The innerHTML of my person div is not showing up when I submit the form. But its creating an object because I see it in the console. Wondering how I can get it to show up like the placeholder one was showing up. My second image shows how in the console the "customer object" shows up, but there is no innerHTML/div showing up on the actual website page.

[image: what I want to occur]

[image: my issue]

```
// add customer

    UI.prototype.addCustomer = function(customer){
    const images = [1,2,3,4,5];
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('person');
    div.innerHTML = `<img src="img/winner_${random}.jpg" alt="">
    <h4 class="person_name">${customer.name}</h4>
    <h4 class="person_lastname">${customer.lastname}</h4>`

    document.querySelector('.pizza_card_list').appendChild(div)

}

//

    function Customer(name,lastname,email){
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;

}


    document.querySelector('.pizza_form').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const name = document.querySelector('.input_name').value;
    const lastname = document.querySelector('.input_lastname').value;
    const email = document.querySelector('.input_email').value;

    let value = ui.checkEmpty(name,lastname,email)

    if(value){
        let customer = new Customer(name,lastname,email)
        console.log(customer);
        ui.showFeedback('Submitted', 'success')
    }
    else{
        ui.showFeedback('some form values empty', 'error')

}


})

}
```

Comment: You are missing some semicolons after `div.innerHTML = '...'`, `document.querySelector('.pizza_card_list').appendChild(div)`, `let customer = new Customer(name,lastname,email)`, `ui.showFeedback('Submitted', 'success')` and `ui.showFeedback('some form values empty', 'error')`. Those could break your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to call the UI.prototype.addCustomer function.

It seems like you're not calling `UI.prototype.addCustomer', you create a new customer with the Customer constructor, but you don't seem to pass that new customer to the UI.prototype.addCustomer function from what I can tell.